# Choose random string from text document

Tags: c#, text, console, document

I've made a program that will ask the user to enter 20 names into a text document. If the file doesn't exist, create a new one, if it does then display the contents.

What I'm trying to do is use a randomiser to randomly pick a name, I've already done that here but I can't get it to work. I want it to read the text file and randomly choose a name from it.
I'm getting no errors and not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Note: What I have also done is made the first name entered (classNames[0] in array) to have an increased chance of being picked.

```
static void increaseChances()
{
    int rand = r.Next(3); //0 = 100%, 1 = 50%, 2 = 33.33% chance, 3 = 25% chance, This number determines the percentage of the first name entered to be picked

    if (rand == 0)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.WriteLine("\nThe winner of the randomiser is: {0} Congratulations! ", classNames[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        Console.WriteLine("\nThe winner of the randomiser is: {0} Congratulations! ", classNames[r.Next(classNames.Length)]);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    }
}
```

Here is what I've got:

```
class Program
{
    static Random r = new Random();
    static string[] classNames = new string[20];

    static void increaseChances()
    {
        int rand = r.Next(3); //0 = 100%, 1 = 50%, 2 = 33.33% chance, 3 = 25% chance, This number determines the percentage of the first name entered to be picked

        if (rand == 0)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.WriteLine("\nThe winner of the randomiser is: {0} Congratulations! ", classNames[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine("\nThe winner of the randomiser is: {0} Congratulations! ", classNames[r.Next(classNames.Length)]);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random RandString = new Random();

        string file = @"C:\names.txt";
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

        if (File.Exists(file))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Names in the text document are: \n");
            foreach (string displayFile in File.ReadAllLines(file))
            Console.WriteLine(displayFile);
            increaseChances();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.Write("\nPress any key to close... ");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
            {
                Console.Write("Enter name number {0}: ", i + 1);
                classNames[i] = Console.ReadLine();
                File.Create(file).Close();
                File.WriteAllLines(file, classNames);
            }

                Console.WriteLine("Writing names to file...");
                increaseChances();
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.Write("Completed! Exiting...");
                Thread.Sleep(1500);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it? You are aware that random isn't really random?

Comment: The important details you forgot is: You do not get any errors, but what is happening that you don't want to happen? What isn't working?

Comment: What I want is for it to read the text file and select a random name from it and display it.

Comment: Your first usage of `r.Next` is wrong. `r.Next(1)` will always give `0`, `r.Next(2)` has a 50/50 chance at `0` or `1` etc. Your next usage of `r.Next` is correct in that it will never return `classNames.Length` and lead to an index exception, but it also has a chance of selecting `0` which will alter your probability of index `0` being selected.

Comment: @whiskybrah - And what does it do now? What goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are not filling your `classNames` array if the file already exists. Therefore your `increaseChances` method can't pick a name from it.

Comment: Yep, fixed I done this:  StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file);
            int i = 0;
            while (i < classNames.Length)
            {

                classNames[i] = sr.ReadLine();
                i++;
            }
            sr.DiscardBufferedData();
            sr.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            sr.BaseStream.Position = 0;